# How to aggregate and show top n item with a mapreduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Every line of my data is a string concatenation of a year and some characters.
I want to get the top 3  characters ordered by descending frequency for each year.

My input is like :

```
2012,A,B,C
2000,C,A,Q,E,P
2001,A,P,B
2000,A,B
2000,A,B,C,D
2012,A, D
```

What I want is an output like:

```
2000: A 4, B 3, C 2
2001: A 1, P 1, B 1
2012: C 2, A 1 , B 1
```

What I did:

1) Mapper

```
String[] words = value.toString().split( ",");
IntStream.range(1, words.length).parallel().forEach(i -> 
context.write(new SimpleEntry<String,String>(words[0], words[i]), new IntWritable(1));)

My mapper's output is: 
key : 2012,A value : 1
key : 2012,B value : 1
key : 2012,C value : 1
key : 2000,C value : 1
key : 2000,A value : 1
key : 2000,Q value : 1
key : 2000,E value : 1
key : 2000,P value : 1
...
```

2) Reducer (I used the predefined IntSumReducer). The output is :

```
key : 2012,A value : 1
key : 2012,B value : 1
key : 2012,C value : 2
key : 2000,C value : 2
key : 2000,A value : 4
key : 2000,Q value : 1
key : 2000,E value : 1
key : 2000,P value : 1
...
```

Now I think that I can chain another mapper with an output like

```
key : 2012 value : A,1
key : 2012 value : B,1
key : 2012 value : C,1
key : 2000 value : C,1
key : 2000 value : A,1
key : 2000 value : Q,1
key : 2000 value : E,1
key : 2000 value : P,1
...
```

and then a reducer to concatenate the value for a given key. 
The output will look like

```
2000: E 1, B 3, C 2, Q 1, A 4, P 1
2001: A 1, P 1, B 1
2012: C 2, A 1 , B 1
...
```

How can I sort the values by the descending frequency and get the top 3?
There is a better way to do this job?